# HTML form handling in Java

Tags: java, forms, post, urlconnection

I am developing a Java project that uses the following website:
http://feedenlarger.com/

The program essentially just inputs a link [ for example http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml ] into the "Enter partial feed URL" box and submits the form. Once the form is submitted I want to download the page that a user would access if they manually filled out the form and clicked the button on the page.

**How can I do this in Java?**

I have managed to successfully download the page with the form using:

```
    private String readWebPage() throws IOException{
        URL u = null;
        URLConnection urlC = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        try{
            u = new URL(this.url);
            urlC = u.openConnection();
            headers = urlC.getHeaderFields();

            bis = new BufferedInputStream(urlC.getInputStream());

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            int byteRead;
            while ((byteRead = bis.read()) != -1)
                builder.append((char) byteRead);

            bis.close();
            return builder.toString();
        } catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Webpage: IO Error");
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

*Note: I'm interested in keeping the headers in memory so using URLConnection or similar is preferable.*

How can I now fill in the form, submit using a POST/GET request and download the next webpage? I have tried downloading the page from the [link](http://feedenlarger.com/makefulltextfeed.php?url=feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml&max=5&links=preserve&exc=&submit=Create%20full%20text%20feed) generated by my browser once the form is submitted but this gives me a "forbidden" error.

The compilable project I have been using is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tpx6luxilq93c18/zeQyaJPzv8)

Comment: Are you doing this for test purposes or because you want to simulate users on background?

Comment: Test purposes. I am trying to learn how to use Java to fill out forms. This is the simplest website/form I could find. Examples using different websites are welcome :)

Comment: If it is for test purposes of your website onyl, you should look into [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) instead to not reinvent the wheel. If you exactly need to th perform GET/POST requests in background (which is really rare but may happen), then you should use another technology like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) that allows reading the whole HTML and keep using URLConnection or [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) to perform the requests to the server.

Comment: All I need is to be able to get the information from the second webpage that opens when the form is submitted. I have experience with webpage parsing using JSOUP, I don't need to parse the second webpage though I just need to be able to download it.

Comment: Is there a way I could download the second page without even loading the first one? That would be the most ideal solution.

Comment: Well, you can take a look on the way you send the request to the second page by using a Network monitor. This way, your application will only simulate sending this request and there won't be any need to pass for the first page. Still, take into account that some (pretty decent and secure) pages may use an identifier for the client e.g. [asp.net viewstate hidden field](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_viewstate.asp) and requires sending it in your requests, so in a case like this you will need to check the first page before to retrieve these fields.

Comment: I've been trying to work out what is causing the "forbidden" message when I just load the url encoded link without visiting the first page. I'm not sure what to look for on the network monitor though, there's no cookies as far as i'm aware

Comment: Check out all the fields you need to sent and which of them are auto generated by the server (usually hidden fields). Basically, you need to check all the elements about how the request is being sent. This can be easily done in Chrome or Firefox + Firebug by pressing F12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Posted this as answer since it is too big to fit in a comment. Also, posted as community wiki in order to avoid earning any rep [or losing it in case somebody doesn't read it this message] ).

This is the result of the network monitor when I sent my last comment on the page:

```
Remote Address:198.252.206.140:80
Request URL:http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23431154/comments
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:es,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,pt;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:322
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:__qca=P0-1914216052-1380726140973; __utma=140029553.1039400677.1380726141.1389622782.1389628108.351; __utmz=140029553.1389047375.333.15.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); sgt=id=dfc633fa-3459-4f24-be6f-ca2ee08908cd; usr=t=f94uBq5WkGsH&s=BDL1eqRYkOQ5&p=[2|2][10|15]; _ga=GA1.2.1039400677.1380726141
Host:stackoverflow.com
Origin:http://stackoverflow.com
Referer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23431154/html-form-handling-in-java?noredirect=1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
comment:Check out all the fields you need to sent and which of them are auto generated by the server (usually hidden fields). Basically, you need to check all the elements about how the request is being sent. This can be easily done in Chrome or Firefox + Firebug by pressing F12.
fkey:bc6f108950fe59611b3f1ebf4caedb31
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:2158
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 02 May 2014 15:21:55 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```

Here's an example of how the Network Monitor looks

[image: example of Network Monitor]

Answer (score 1):

Based on your scenario, we can implement using this **HMTLUnit** and **Selenium** tools.

You can input the text using HtmlTextInput and submit the form to navigate to the second page using anchor tags.

We have full support for HTML Tags in HTMLUnit.
Using the HTMLInput set the value in the first page using **`setAttributeValue("some text")`** method and proceed to the further page using the button or anchor tag you are looking for.

```
HtmlAnchor anchor = (HtmlAnchor)page.getHtmlElementById("second_page_link");
    page = (HtmlPage) anchor.click();
```